# Usage of iBatis in the program

Tags: ibatis

Hello folks,
              I want to learn iBatis.I tried running a sample code on internet.But I am getting many exceptions like ClassNOTFoundException,IOException.Please guide me about it.I want to know many things like where should I place my XML files whether under src or under my package or under the project,is any specific installation,setting is required to run the iBatis program.Kindly tell me the resources names which I can refer for my learning.I tried this code.
http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/ibatis/ibatis-selection.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately roseindia's website is not updated and most people who commented on that blog had quite a number off issues with even compiling and executing the codes.

One good place to start learning iBatis even to an expert level is tutorialspoint. You can access their iBatis tutorials using this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ibatis/index.htm  and you also have an option to download a copy of the entire tutorial in pdf format using this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ibatis/ibatis_tutorial.pdf so that you can still read it even while offline. They also provide a variety of other programming tutorials. This is indeed a good place to start.